# The method of ghusl

Tags: ghusl, self-purification

Asalam alaykum brothers and sisters

I have a question about ghusl, I want to know if the steps I am taking to purify myself are correct.

1: I say bismillah before entering the washroom

2: I take a normal shower to remove any physical impurity

3: u make intention for ghusl and rinse nose and mouth, then I was the entire body from head to toe

(I do fard ghusl, but u have heard that it says in the quran that if you make intention and wash every part of the body, you are pure)

Jazak allah

Answer (score 1):

Bismillah,

Niyyah (intention) for ghusl is Sunnah and saying Tasmiyah (Bismillah) before ghusl is Mustahabb according to Hanafi fiqh.

The steps of ghusl are as follows (Hanafi fiqh):

```
 1. Washing hands, 3 times;
 2. Miswak, 1 time;
 3. Mazmaza (washing mouth), 3 times;
 4. Istinshaq (rinsing nose), 3 times;
 5. Washing face, 3 times;
 6. Washing right and left hands with elbows, 3 times;
 7. Wiping head, 1 time;
 8. Washing all of body (water must reach every part), 3 times;
 9. Washing feet with ankles, 3 times;
```

Based on following hadith:

> **Narrated Maimuna:**
>
> (the wife of the Prophet) Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) performed ablution
> like that for the prayer but did not wash his feet. He washed off the
> discharge from his private parts and then poured water over his body.
> He withdrew his feet from that place (the place where he took the
> bath) and then washed them. And that was his way of taking the bath of
> Janaba.
>
> [Sahih al-Bukhari 249](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:249)

Answer (score 0):

If a person makes the water reach all parts of his body, by whatever means, then he has removed the major impurity and purified himself properly, including rinsing the mouth and nose, his ghusl is accepted. Saying Bismillah is not fard in both wudu and ghusl.
The complete way, which is doing ghusl as the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) did it. When he wanted to do ghusl in the case of janaabah, he would wash his hands, then wash his private part and anywhere else that the impurity had reached, then he would do complete wudoo’, then he would wash his head three times with water, then he would wash the rest of his body. This is how complete ghusl is done.

Source: https://islamqa.info/en/answers/83172/complete-vs-acceptable-ghusl